# node.js POST request to another server

Tags: node.js, express, post

I have a node.js application (let's say application 1) which generates dummy data and pushes the data to mongodb at localhost:3000. This application is created by using node.js, express and mongodb.

In another application (application 2) I am using node.js, express and mqtt. In this application I want to collect the data generated by application 1 and this application is running on port number 3001.

My question is, how I can post the data from application 1 to application 2 or how I can get the data from application 1 to application 2?

Answer (score 0):

That is a very vague and open-ended question. There are many, many ways this could be accomplished, of varying degrees of difficulty, cost, and scaling capability. You should probably start by narrowing the focus of your question to figure out what you really need before posting, but just for simplicity's sake, why don't you try a simple POST from one node application to the other?

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do. Single POST request to another node application to other, how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Either with plain node http/s libs: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback or with something like axios or request, packages available on npmjs.org https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a jobe for TCP Sockets.

The thing is, if you want to **push** data to somewhere else you need to first open a connection between the application and then you will be able to **push** between them (Just like chat application).

The how is where the fun begins. There are many options to chose from when implementing:

1. **Direct TCP connection (Pub/Sub)** - implement a TCP server in `App1` and allow `App2` to connect to it (see [net](https://nodejs.org/api/index.html)).
2. **Pub/Sub** Server - similar to the first but you use some kind of intermediate between them. This is nice due to `App2` don't have to directly be compelled to `App1` (see [Redis pub/sub](https://redis.io/topics/pubsub) for example)
3. **Queue** - This is the choice if your data is **stateful** and every pace of data generated has to get to `App2` regardless if it was down for some time. The Queue will get fill and wait for `App2` to connect to it back only then the Queue will start emptying (see [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) for example)